# 2 column Flatlist component not distributing columns properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist component that is 2 rows but the columns don't distribute properly. I'm having trouble styling it to achieve this.
My Flatlist:

```
<FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
        numColumns={2}
        data={this.props.route.params.data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.view}
            onPress={() =>
              item.subcategories
                ? this.props.navigation.navigate('Browse', {
                    screen: 'Subcategories',
                    params: {data: item.subcategories},
                  })
                : this.props.navigation.navigate('Browse', {
                    screen: 'Products',
                    params: {id: item.id},
                  })
            }
            underlayColor="grey">
            <View style={styles.view}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
```

Style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  list: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  view: {
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignContent: 'stretch',
    margin: 1,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 2,
  },
  title: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    padding: 5,
    width: '100%',
  },
});
```

What it looks like:

[image]

I know I can set the width to a number, but I want it to dynamically change with screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try add `width: '50%'` to the view style or `width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2`

Comment: That makes it look like this: https://imgur.com/a/jaxl4Ec

Comment: Oh the dimensions way worked! Now the boxes don't go the full height if they are only 1 line: https://imgur.com/a/UDilZyd

Comment: It just makes the first row the full height